# wkhtmltopdf export pdf with image doesnt work, image look linke not found

Tags: php, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

[Image dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ0MP.png)

When i trying to export pdf with image - and use dump(dd) i can see my image, but when export them i have this problem [image doesnt render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3vUu.png)

What i need to do? may be i don't have required module on server? or i need change my html?

```
@if(isset($photo) && count($photo) > 0)
    <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
        @foreach($photo as $image)
        <img height="200" width="200" src="{{$image}}">x
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't find the images. I'm not too familiar with Laravel, but one of these should work:

- Relative path `/img/file.jpg`
- Path as you'd enter in the browser `https://example.com/img/file.jpg`
- Path as you'd enter in the command line `/var/www/img/file.jpg` or `C:\www\img\file.jpg` on Windows

I forget which one it needs, but try all three and I'm sure one of them will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the latest version of wkhtmltopdf

sudo wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb

It worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04